# Google Timeline chart: two horizontal axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

Good day, guys!

I use a timeline chart to visualize a vacations' schedule in my organization.
Now it looks like this:
[the bottom of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJAxC.png)

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart');
        var chart = new window.google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new window.google.visualization.DataTable();
 
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'BarDates' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
        var beginStr = "";
        var endStr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var elems = rows[i].split(',');
            var begin = new Date(elems[1]);
            beginStr = (begin.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + begin.getDate() : begin.getDate()) + '/' +
            (begin.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (begin.getMonth() + 1) : begin.getMonth() + 1);
            var end = new Date(elems[2]);
            endStr = (end.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + end.getDate() : end.getDate()) + '/' +
            (end.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (end.getMonth() + 1) : end.getMonth() + 1);
            if (beginStr === endStr) {
                isHidden = true;
            }
            if (elems.length > 1) {
                dataTable.addRow([elems[0], beginStr + ' - ' + en`enter code here`dStr, begin, end, elems[3]]);
            } else {
                count = elems[0] - 0;
            }
        }
 
        var options = {
            tooltip: { isHtml: true },
            timeline: {
                colorByRowLabel: true
            },
            width: $('#chart').width(),
            hAxis: {
                minValue: new Date(date - 0, 0, 0),
                maxValue: new Date(date - 0 + 1, 0, 0)
            },
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        };
 
        $('#chart').height(count * 42 + 60);
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

In addition, there is a very strange behavior of months' names. They are changing every refreshing of a page from English names to my native names.

Please, help me cope with the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't help you with what your first problem because you didn't state it in a way I can understand. I assume the problem is in the question title, but I don't know what you mean.

For the second issue - language selection - you can explicitly tell Google Charts to use a specific localization when it loads. I don't know why it would be inconsistent. Instructions for setting the language can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale

Use the standard 2-letter language code for the language you want it to use. For examples: en=english, fr=french, ja=japanese.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on my second question. 
And sorry that I wasn't clear about the first question. I try to rephrase it.
I have labels along x-axis (Feb, Mar, Apr and so on). I want it not only on the bottom of the chart but also on the top of the chart.